# Google Custom Search--changing the 'no results' message

Tags: javascript, html, google-custom-search

I've found myself in a position where I need to change the 'no results' message of my google custom search. I know you can change the message in the CSE control panel but I've found out that it doesn't allow for things such as line breaks or dot points, which I need.

Is there any way I can add these things into the 'no results' message with Javascript or similar languages? If so, how? For reference, the google custom search I'm using has the 'results only' layout.

Answer (score 2):

I have also come across this issue. But the thing is that CSE just doesn't give you that degree of control. 
If you want this kind of customization ability, then it will be better to switch to an alternate search service. Algolia is a big player in the field, and they provide an API for everything. While this will give you the desired control, it will also make the whole search integration process tedious. 
Another option is to go for a turnkey solution ExpertRec or Addsearch. Of the two, only ExpertRec lets you change the no results message.
The benefit here is that you can add custom HTML in place of the no results message in their [dashboard](https://cse.expertrec.com/csedashboard/looknfeel/basic/results), which will give you the degree of control you are looking for.